# How to use XSLT attribute with for each select

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I want to use a attribute inside select keyword.

Here is my xml

```
<root rowselement="root/a/b">
<a>
    <b var="target1"/>
</a>
<a>
    <b var="target2"/>
</a>
```

and xslt

```
<xsl:for-each select="/root/@rowselement">
<xsl:value-of select="@var"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

and expected output

> target1
>   target2

but it doesn't work , what can i do?

Answer (score 1):

The attribute contains a string, and you want to interpret the string as an XPath expression, and evaluate that expression. This is often called "dynamic evaluation" - evaluating an XPath expression that is not known until run-time.

Many XSLT processors have an extension function capable of doing this - some use the EXSLT extension dyn:eval() - but it varies from processor to processor.

There's nothing in the W3C standard to enable this until you get to XSLT 3.0, which offers the xsl:evaluate instruction.

Comment: can you give me a example or tutorial link for this ?

Comment: What XSLT processor are you using?

Comment: I don't know that processor so I can't tell you what it implements. dyn:evaluate is described at http://exslt.org/dyn/functions/evaluate/ That page claims that libxslt implements it, that might be what you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:for-each select="descendant::*/@var">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/><xsl:if test="following::*/@var"><xsl:text>, </xsl:text></xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I believe they want to use the path in `root/@rowselement` to control which elements to select for output.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not defined well enough, IMHO: XPath expressions can be much more complex than what your example shows.

If your expression will always be as simple as that, you could solve this by doing something like the following example:

**Test Input**

```
<root rowselement="/root/a/b">
    <a>
        <a var="target0"/>
        <b var="target1"/>
    </a>
    <b>
        <a var="target4"/>
        <b var="target5"/>
    </b>
    <a>
        <b var="target2"/>
        <b var="target3"/>
    </a>
</root>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:variable name="path" select="/root/@rowselement" />

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:variable name="path-to-me">
        <xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::*">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('/', name())"/>
        </xsl:for-each>    
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:if test="$path-to-me = $path">
        <xsl:value-of select="@var"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
target1
target2
target3
```

Note that in my example the given path expression begins with the root node `/`.

Comment: Good suggestion, plus one.